# Rounded Edges in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

how to make a square edges into round edges?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of another question, just one second

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to try jQuery corner plugin

[Jquery.corners](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Answer (score 1):

Rounded corners in a css3 feature. But Internet explorer doesn't support fully all css3 properties. A solve to this problem is the use of http://css3pie.com/. A javascript solution to provide css3 properties for ie.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in pure CSS alone, you will need something extra:

http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. There is a way, see http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not provide the functionality necessary to do this via CSS, this will be (is) included in IE9. To create rounded corners for IE8 the easiest way is to create images and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Download: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

Now whenever you need a rounder corner apply this css:

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(/path/to/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```